# How do I create a progress control in MFC with rounded corners?

Tags: c++, mfc, progress-bar

I need to create a progress bar with rounded corners in a MFC application.  I have tried using a combination of CreateRoundRectRgn() and SetWindowRgn(), which has the effect of making the control disappear completely.  I also tried using a transparent GIF overlay that would be drawn on top of the progress bar, but I could only get the overlay to be drawn behind the progress bar.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi you can look to this article [http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/cskinprogress.aspx](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/cskinprogress.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the link - it seems that it will do the trick, but I need to figure out how to integrate it with the rest of my solution, and that may take some time - will post again with result.

Comment: No problem just ask )

Comment: The solution provided only rounded the bar itself - the containing box is what needs to be rounded, and the code provided does not do this.